# Writing data to USB device

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, usb, libusb

I have a requirement to send some commands to a device(Cash drawer) connected to the USB port to open the drawer. The device may be from different vendors and manufacturers, so i need a common mechanism to write to the devices just like writing to serial port. Can i use LibUsb win32 to achieve it, if so there are two things Filter driver and device driver which one should i use?

Comment: AFAIK, you can only use libusb as "device driver", if real driver for device is not installed, otherwise you use filter driver.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully done this using [WPD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388998%28vs.85%29.aspx) (not for newbies). Perhaps not suitable for all scenarios, but it certainly is a good start. I would guess that there is a standard command to 'open device'. Some WPD commands [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff597554%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Otherwise I would reverse-engineer the device command needed to open the drawer using [busdog](http://code.google.com/p/busdog/) and try to write this command to the USB device using the [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs.